# Converting String to UTF-8 and save it in a file

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, java-8

I have a String in **Java**, this string represents the content of a XML file (That I'm generating in other process), I have a problem with the codification, in the header of the XML I have `UTF-8` but when I tried to parse it I gets an error related with the codification, exactly:

```
Byte not valid 2 pf the sequence UTF-8 of 4 bytes
```

So, I opened the file with **Notepad++** and it says it's with ANSI codification. I was thinking in convert the String to `UTF-8` before save it in the file, I made this with:

```
byte[] encoded = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But then,how I save it in the file?I want the user be able to open the XML file in any text editor, but now I have bytes.How I save it?

Comment: Use a `PrintWriter`, and write the content as a `String`.

Comment: Files *always* consist of bytes, regardless of how you store it. Whether you can open it with a text editor is not affected. Just write the bytes to a file, there are plenty of ways to do it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks! that's working!

Answer (score 0):

The following should do

```
// Ensure that the stated encoding in the XML is UTF-8:
//                              $1______________________ $2_____ $3_
content = content.replaceFirst("(<\\?xml[^>]+encoding=\")([^\"]*)(\")",
        "$1UTF-8$3");

byte[] encoded = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Files.writeBytes(Paths.get("... .xml"), encoded);
```

For editing one needs a UTF-8 capable editor (JEdit, Notepad++) - under Windows.

Notepad++ should recognize the file, you could reload it with the right encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Files.write(Paths.get("output.xml"), encoded);`.