# Why is my JavaScript file formatted oddly in IDEA?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, notepad++

I have a .js file. When I open it in Notepad++ the first two lines look fine like this:

```
(function(ns, $, undefined){
if(!ns.lang) { ns.lang = {}; }
```

When I open the file in Intellij it looks like this:

```
( f u n c t i o n ( n s ,   $ ,   u n d e f i n e d ) { 
 i f ( ! n s . l a n g )   {   n s . l a n g   =   { } ;   }
```

It's not visible here. StackOverflow inserts space between nevery character but here is how it looks like in Intellij and in Chrome's inspect(images below). Weird character gets inserted between every code character.

What could be causing this? Notepad++ and Intellij is in UTF-8

[image]

[image]

Comment: looking at it in a hex editor might provide insight

Comment: Sounds like you have some 0-space Unicode characters throughout the file, where did you get this JS file from?

Comment: It's written from Java using Files.writeString(). Method says that it's UTF-8 by default

Comment: It looks to me like UCS-2 or UTF16 that is being mis-interpreted/converted incorrectly at some point as UTF8/ASCII

Comment: Could you double check what encoding does Notepad++ think the file is using?

Comment: If Java is producing the file, you might want to edit that into the question and tags, that is probably more of a Java question than anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559993/converting-string-to-utf-8-and-save-it-in-a-file?noredirect=1&lq=1  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java  a couple java threads you might find useful.